# Connect 5 external harddisks to a single usb port

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, power-supply

I want to connect 5 external hardisks to single USB port. I think that can be done by giving some sort of powersource to individual external HDs. How much voltage should I provide to individual hardisks and what points in usb port are for power supply?

Comment: For perspective on bandwidth, an external SATA drive has roughly the same data transfer rate as a USB3 port.  So a single drive connected to a single USB3 port will give you roughly the performance the drive is designed for.  Five drives won't all be moving data at the same time but divide the performance by the number of drives operating concurrently on a USB3 hub.  USB3 is 10 times the speed of USB2, so if you are using USB2, divide those numbers by 10.  That puts you in the speed range of a 16x DVD.  If you have ever tried to run a LiveDVD session, you know what that speed is like.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to connect 5 external hardisks to single USB port.

That is possible, but you will need an USB hub and the speed will be limited because all data has to pass though a single USB connector when going to the computer. Expect about 20-35 MB/sec if you use USB2 and half that when you copy from one of those five disks to another of those five.

> I think that can be done by giving some sort of powersource to individual
>   external HDs.

All harddisks need power. For internal drives this is done via a cable from the PSU. For external drives you have two options:

1. Plug in power cable into the relevant socket on the external drive and the data cable (e.g. the USB cable, or the eSAT cable) into the data socket.
2. Or try to power the drive directly from the USB bus.

The latter works as follows:

- The electronics in the external drive casing power up when connected. They draw limited power.  (and they are not allowed to draw more!)
- The controller in your USB devices negotiates with your PC. It will identioty itself (brand, model, type of device, ...) and for external drives it will request more power.
- If the PC grants more power it can then spin up the drive.

Note that the PC does not need to grant more power. It might already be at its limit for that USB power and in that case it will decline. The result is that your drive does not spin up and can not be used.

Now even if the PC grant max legal power you are still limited to 5 units of 100mA power for USB (and 6 units at 150mA for USB3)

That means max 500mA at 5 volt for USB2. That is barely enough to spin up a 2½ inch HDD. It is not enough to run five of them.

> How much voltage should I provide to individual hardisks.

5 volt.

> and what points in USB port are for power supply?

What you probably are looking for it:

1. A power USB hub  (That is an USB hub with its own power supply which can pass some of that on to the drives).
2. Or drives with their own power supply.  A surprising number of external drives do have a socket for these, though the PSU's themselves are rarely bundled at sale.

Comment: For 2, these would often be external drives. You might also use a split USB cable, but that sort of defeats the purpose of plugging in that many USB drives into one ports.